# O que significa <!-- //--> em HTML / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms

Passei por um problema onde era apresentado uma *tag* `<script>` e continha esses caracteres de comentário HTML.

Exemplo de função

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  function Alert(){
  alert("apenas uma função exemplo")
  }
//-->
</script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="Alert()">Funcão Exemplo</button>
    </body>
      </html>
```

ASe você colocar essa estrutura em uma aplicação ASP.NET WebForms, e simplesmente retirar a *tag* comentário do final do *script*, ele não funciona.

```html
<html>
  <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
  function Alert(){
  alert("apenas uma função exemplo")
  }
 
</script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <button onClick="Alert()">Funcão Exemplo</button>
    </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: `<!-- comentário -->` = HTML --- 
`/* comentario */` = javascripts, css, asp e php

Comment: onde voce viu isso? joga no w3c pra ver o que e isso @Marcos Costa

Comment: @Assanges em um sistema legado da empresa onde eu trabalho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isso é uma *tag* de comentário de HTML. Ele inicia com o `!--` e termina com o `--`. Sem esse comentário o *parser* do HTML pode se perder.

É comum usá-lo para "esconder" um *script* JavaScript. Só que este se complicará com esse `--` do HTML. Então usa o `//` que é o comentário do JavaScript para ignorar este código que no fundo é do HTML.

Notou que parece uma coisa só mas no fundo são duas construções diferentes, e mais, de linguagens diferentes?

Se não tiver isso vai considerar que o comentário não terminou e todo o resto será desconsiderado como código HTML útil.

Este é um excelente motivo para não usar este tipo de coisa. Na verdade hoje em dia isto é bem menos usado. A recomendação geral é não ter um código JavaScript dentro do HTML. Crie um arquivo externo e inclua ele pelos meios tradicionais. Fica mais organizado, tem vantagens diversas além de evitar esta confusão.

Isto independe da tecnologia que está usando no servidor.

Exemplos:

```
Tem um texto aqui <!-- the middle of --> com comentário no meio.

<!--
Pode ter
várias linhas de
comentário
-->

<div class="exemplo">
Pode ter uma construção normal e simular o *inline* desde que abra e feche.<br>
</div> <!-- /.exemplo -->
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/Comment.js).

Answer (score 2):

Utilizado para Javascript, é apenas um consenso de orientação do fim da função.
Como por exemplo comentários para demarcar início e fim de uma determinada delimitação de código, eu mesmo utilizo isto para me identificar.

Olhe se isto ajuda.

```js
function teste(){
   alert('sou um robô');  
}
// **>
```

```html
<div><!-- div do conteudo x -->
 <p>yyyyyyyyyy</p> 
</div> <!-- fim do conteudo da div x -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Isso é um comentário de código HTML. Até onde eu sei isso foi usado no passado, para fazer com que navegadores que não tinham suporte ao Javascript não tivessem problemas com essa "nova tag" `<script>`.